# ZF2: How to make Zend\Validator\Hostname accept url strings with and without http:// or https://

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I use Zend\Validator\Hostname to validate an input string containing a url. The problem is that it only accepts URLs of type mydomain.com and not with a http:// or https:// protocol prefix. What is the best way to achieve the desired behaviour?

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name'     => 'shop_link',
                'required' => false,
                'filters'  => array(
                        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                        array(
                            'name'    => 'StringLength',
                            'options' => array(
                                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                'min'      => 1,
                                'max'      => 100,
                            ),
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name'    => 'Hostname',
                            'options' => array(
                                'allow'       => \Zend\Validator\Hostname::ALLOW_DNS, // Allow these hostnames
                                'useIdnCheck' => true,  // Check IDN domains
                                'useTldCheck' => true,  // Check TLD elements
                                'ipValidator' => null,  // IP validator to use
                            ),
                        ),
                ),
        )));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I don't have 50 reputation to comment Sam's answer, but Hostname::ALLOW_URI doesn't work. And didn't work year ago - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13902180/822947. And shouldn't work, if you look at the source code. Strange that it has two upvotes.

```
$validator = new \Zend\Validator\Hostname();
$validator->setAllow($validator::ALLOW_DNS | $validator::ALLOW_URI);
var_dump($validator->isValid('http://domain.com')); // false!
```

Answer (score 4):

There's two things you should try, first one will probably already be your desired result:

```
'options' => array(
    'allow' => Hostname::ALLOW_URI | Hostname::ALLOW_DNS,
    ....
)
```

Allowing the URI, at least going by the RFC-Specification, should include the validation of the Scheme...

In addition to that, there is also a Filter that you may want to know about: [`Zend\Filter\UriNormalize`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.filter.set.html#urinormalize)

Answer (score 3):

I've used *Uri* validator and disabled *allowRelative* (set to false) for validating URIs:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'url',
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Uri',
                'options' => array(
                    'allowRelative' => false
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: When setting `allowRelative` to `false` I now correctly validate the URI `Not a valid URI` to be valid. What does the relative path mean anyway? The documentation doesn't really seem to elaborate...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function isValidUrl($url) {
    $uri = new \Zend\Validator\Uri();
    if (!$uri->isValid($url)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $parseUrl = parse_url($url);
    if(!isset($parseUrl['host']) || empty($parseUrl['host'])) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $validator = new \Zend\Validator\Hostname(\Zend\Validator\Hostname::ALLOW_DNS);
    if (!$validator->isValid($parseUrl['host'])) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (!filter_var($parseUrl['host'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```